# jQuery Based Survey Building Interface

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop, survey

In the past, I have used a few survey building sites to build, well, surveys.  Now, I am wanting to build a similar interface.  Some of the key features I remember are:

- Drag/Drop of question "types" and ability to sort and order.
- Inline editing of the content once a question has been created.

I am familiar with jQuery.  Does anyone know of any good jQuery widgets that have similar features to this?  If not, does anyone have any suggestions for how to go about putting something like this together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery UI is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use a combination of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) for the drag and drop capability.  For the sorting and filtering of the questions (individual view rendering a single model) in the survey (collection of individual views each with a single corresponding model) I would use [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).

Backbone gives you the ability to create an JavaScript UI with models and views.  The models would be the question data and the view would be the display of the question.  Backbone.js also has the concept of collections as well.  These collections of models can be sorted, filted, etc.  Backbone.js as makes it possible to enforce the [MVC pattern](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Introduction).  Simply put, your models should not have a reference to their respective views.

Check out this [simple TODO application](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples-todos) to get an idea of how backbone.js could benefit your survey application.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting backjone.js.  I had not heard of it, but, I really like how it handles the views.  I have a pretty good framework in place to handle the models, but, have struggled to work out a good way of handling the data binding.